# subprocess.Popen can't find file

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/flock -n', 'blah.lockfile', 'python3 executer.py', "some_arg ,"&"])
```

I do `subprocess.Popen("pwd")` and it prints the same path I am running the code.

However I get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/flock -n'
```

Why's Python not finding the flock file for locking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/flock', '-n', 'blah.lockfile', 'python3 executer.py', 'some_arg', '&'])
```